# how to get BRANCH_NAME in jenkins windows command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

how to get `BRANCH_NAME` in jenkins windows command?

I tried

```
echo BRANCH_NAME
echo %BRANCH_NAME%
echo env.BRANCH_NAME
```

but jenkins console print the string `"BRANCH_NAME"` not the value of branch name.

I need branch_name to create in IIS dynamic aplications based on branch name and create a folder with branc_name

Comment: What kind of job are you configuring? Freestyle or do you use either scripted or declarative pipeline? Also, the environment vatriables are only available for running jobs.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Pipeline Multibranch Plugin(https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin)

Use env.BRANCH_NAME or Just BRANCH_NAME

For other environment-variables go to (<%http://localhost:8080%>/env-vars.html)